# Tkinter with OOP in 2 different classes, with the "circular imports" error

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, canvas

I'm making a chess game.
I've created a main file with the Tkinter code in a class "Window". In this class, I created a canvas.
Then I've created a second file with the name "pieces", where I put the behaviour of the different pieces. In this one, I have a superclass "Pieces", and a subclass "Bishop" (because I haven't created the classes for the other pieces yet)

What I tried first to do, is to create a bishop's icon in the constructor of the class "Bishop".
My class "Bishop" has the argument "color", so that, when we create an object "Bishop", we can choose if he's black or white.
So I wrote :

```
if self.color == "black":
    icon_path = 'black_bishop.png'
elif self.color == "white":
    icon_path = 'white_bishop.png'

self.icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
main.Window.canvas.create_image(x_position, y_position, self.icon)
```

The problem is, when I create a new object of the bishop, it makes a loop.

I don't really know how to fix this, a solution would be to put the whole code in the same file, but I don't like it because it's not clean.

If you need the whole code, I can give it to you.

that's the complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CSP\PycharmProjects\chess_game\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pieces
  File "C:\Users\CSP\PycharmProjects\chess_game\pieces.py", line 3, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\Users\CSP\PycharmProjects\chess_game\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    fen = Window()
  File "C:\Users\CSP\PycharmProjects\chess_game\main.py", line 20, in __init__
    pieces.Bishop("black", 5, 5)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pieces' has no attribute 'Bishop' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

---

I've written `import main` in the file pieces, because I want to create the image **in** the constructor of the class Bishop, I thought it was cleaner than do it in the class Windows, because I would have to do I 32 times (one per piece) and it would be very heavy.

And to create the image in the class bishop, I need to import the module main (because I use canvas.create_image(), and the canvas is in the class Windows)

But if I write `import main` it makes a loop, so do you have an idea to fix this?

Here's the code, very simplified

### main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import pieces

#GUI class
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("My chess game")

        self.frame = Frame(self.window, bg='#41B77F')
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width=500, height=500, bg="skyblue", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        bishop = Bishop("black",5 , 5)
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES)


win = Window()
win.window.mainloop()
```

### pieces.py

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import main

#superclass
class Pieces:
    def __init__(self, color, x_position, y_position):
        self.color = color
        self.x_position = x_position
        self.y_position = y_position

#subclass
class Bishop(Pieces):
    def __init__(self, color, x_position, y_position):
        super().__init__(color, x_position, y_position)

        if self.color == "black":
            icon_path = 'black_bishop.png'
        elif self.color == "white":
            icon_path = 'white_bishop.png'

        self.icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
        main.Window.canvas.create_image(x_position, y_position, image=self.icon)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices
I did not do the post so well, I'm new on this site
I will do better the next time

Comment: I instantiate it in the Windows class

Comment: I try to make the Bishop give back an image as you said, but even if Window and Bishop both are in the same file, I have the error "name 'Bishop' is not defined" (The code is the same as before, but in the same file)

I will try to follow your second advice to create a method that makes that instead

Comment: I thought about it, and I'm annoyed that I can't create this Image inside the Bishop constructor, because I would be so much easier to manipulate this icon.
For exemple, later I will have to create a method move() inside the Bishop class and if the image belonged to the Bishop object, I think we could write : bishop.icon.remove, and create a new icon in another place

Comment: I added the Bishop instanciation that I forgot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with Model/View approach of writing code, it will help you find your way around `tkinter` applications. In such a case you would place all the code relating to views in one class and all the data is managed in the Model class(es).

In your case, you could start with the structure illustrated below and grow from it:

```
# model.py
from tkinter import *
class GameModel():
    # maintains game state/data
    # may include positions of pieces on board
    # number of moves made by each player
    pass

#superclass, inherits from Tk().Canvas 
class Pieces(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, color, x_position, y_position):
        self.color = color
        self.x_position = x_position
        self.y_position = y_position

#subclass
class Bishop(Pieces):
    def __init__(self, color, x_position, y_position):
        super().__init__(color, x_position, y_position)

        if self.color == "black":
            icon_path = 'black_bishop.png'
        elif self.color == "white":
            icon_path = 'white_bishop.png'

        self.icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
        # main.Fenetre.canvas.create_image(x_position, y_position, image=self.icon)
        self.create_image(x_position, y_position, image=self.icon)
        # because bishop inherits from pieces which inherits from Canvas, its possible
        # to call .create_image() from within Bishop class using self.create_image()


# gameinterface.py
from tkinter import *
#GUI/View class
class GameInterface():
    def __init__(self, window: Tk()):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = Frame(self.window, bg='#41B77F')
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width=500, height=500, bg="skyblue", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES)

    def play(self, game: GameModel):
        # the game objects give access to state of game and all data
        self.window.mainloop()

# main.py
from tkinter import *
def main() -> None:
    """Entry point to gameplay."""
    window = Tk()
    # window = Tk()

    #set title and position at center of screen
    window.title("My chess game") 

    # game object gives you access to all relevant data
    game = GameModel()

    # app object gives you access to view 
    app = GameInterface(window)

    # app.play combines the model and the view
    app.play(game)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks wandesky, I took a lot of time to understand your code but it helped me a lot
So I continued with instanciate an object of the class Bishop, but I didn't know where to do this so I did it in the constructor of the class GameInterface
I got this error AttributeError: 'Bishop' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: In the same file that you have your Bishop class, make sure you `import tkinter as tk`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a reference to the window in `Bishop`, you have to pass it as an argument:

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage

class Pieces:
    def __init__(self, color, x_position, y_position):
        self.color = color
        self.x_position = x_position
        self.y_position = y_position

#subclass
class Bishop(Pieces):
    def __init__(self, win, color, x_position, y_position):
        super().__init__(color, x_position, y_position)

        if self.color == "black":
            icon_path = 'black_bishop.png'
        elif self.color == "white":
            icon_path = 'white_bishop.png'

        self.icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
        win.canvas.create_image(x_position, y_position, image=self.icon)
```

Comment: You need to save the item ID returned by `create_image(...)`, otherwise it cannot be updated later, for example moving to another position.